# Problems Including the sqlLitePlugin in phonegap cli-5.2.0 build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

In config.xml

Have tried the following:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.millerjames01.sqlite-plugin" />
```

which gives

Error - Some official plugins have to be updated if using PhoneGap >= 4.0.0. Please upgrade the version of any plugins that may include the following file: SQLitePlugin.java

Have tried

```
<gap:plugin name="com.millerjames01.sqlite-plugin" source="npm'/>
```

This build was fine before the Upate.

Comment: did  you added plugin using CLI?

Comment: I'm using adobe phonegap build. So am calling the plugins in the config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

@user3617712

A  bad practice, one that's even recommend by Cordova and Phonegap, is to NOT set the version of your compiler and plugins. The recent upgrade by Phonegap and *Phonegap Build* reinforces that this is a *bad idea*.

In addition, you may need to add the `white-list`, the plugin and CSP, if you have not already.

**Here is what you need to know**

Over the last two (2) weeks Cordova has made some major changes. The documentation has NOT caught up. I don't expect it will catch up for at least a few weeks. You have two (2) options:

1) Set your Compiler version to something before Cordova 4.0.0

**QUICK FIX** Add this to your `config.xml`
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`

2) Add version to your compiler and your plugins

From [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) you have hit:

- #6 **Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**
- #7 **Not setting "version" for you plugins**
- #11 **You need to get your plugins from NPM now and set the version.**

#### For #6 & #7

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a set of cascading errors.
>
> Luckily for all of us, Holly Schinsky has written a nice blog post to explain it all: **(NOTE: Holly has not had time to update the article since the move to NPM, use the NPM names, not the names she is using.)**
>
> *Cordova/PhoneGap Version Confusion*
>   http://devgirl.org/2014/11/07/cordovaphonegap-version-confusion/

#### For #11

> The rules regarding sourcing your plugins can be rather confusing. The best thing to do is read the blog posts - below. Developers that use CLI can source from github, again see the blog post.
>
> 2015-10-09 - Without announcment, tweet, or blog, the repository change a full week before it was scheduled. I can do nothing, but complain.... This is damm annoying.
>
> NEW NEW [Cordova npm search page](http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/)
>
> Blog Posts Related to #11
>
> - [Cordova Plugins Registry becomes immutable](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/09/08/CPR-readonly.html) 2015/09/08)
> - [Plugins Release and Moving plugins to npm](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html) 2015/04/21
> - [List of the Latest *Core* Plugins and their versions](http://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/06/22/plugins-release.html) June 22, 2015